# Unable to connect to the server: net/http: TLS handshake timeout (from local to GCP cluster)

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine

I create two Kubernetes clusters in the same google project.
Last week I couldn't connect one of them.

```
jascao@mac ~ % gcloud container clusters get-credentials my-test-cluster --region us-central1 --project ****
Fetching cluster endpoint and auth data.
kubeconfig entry generated for my-test-cluster.
jascao@mac ~ % kubectl get namespace
NAME              STATUS   AGE
consul            Active   27d

jascao@mac ~ % gcloud container clusters get-credentials my-test-cluster2 --region us-central1 --project ****
Fetching cluster endpoint and auth data.
kubeconfig entry generated for my-test-cluster2.
jascao@mac ~ % kubectl get namespace
Unable to connect to the server: net/http: TLS handshake timeout
```

I have tried the next methods, and all not working

1. restart the mac
2. add the Memory of docker.
3. delete the kubectl config and reconnect
4. relogin

So does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Comment: Might be the firewall, do you have any rules having difference for my-test-cluster and my-test-cluster2?

Comment: Have you been able to connect to `my-test-cluster2` before?  Any chance that it is a private cluster without a public endpoint?  One thing to try would be to launch `Cloud Shell` ( https://console.cloud.google.com/home/dashboard?cloudshell=true) in the Google Web Console and see if it works from there first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a kubectl version issue.
I install the kubectl with this command

```
gcloud components install kubectl
```

but gcloud did not supply the newest version recently, so I met the issue.
So I uninstall the the kubectl and reinstall the kubectl with brew and fix the issue.